# Can't access my Laravel application through domain URL after configuring everything

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, vps, apache2.4

I'm looking for some advice on possible issues/fixes for my laravel application. I currently have a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04, Apache/2.4 & php7.2. I have currently stored my Laravel project within the directory - **/var/www/html/laravel**

I have installed all of the necessary packages, including Composer, Laravel Installer and set up the required permissions for the directories:

```
chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/laravel
chmod -R 755 /var/www/laravel
chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/storage
```

I have also configured the **/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf** with:

```
<code>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName laravel
ServerAlias www.laravel.co.uk
ServerAdmin webmaster@local.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public

<Directory /var/www/html/laravel>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Once I configured this, I also enabled the laravel and rewrite module using:

```
a2ensite laravel.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I restarted the apache server but when I access the site through the web browser, it still returns the error

> "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Any ideas you might have would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: you are missing server name and alias configs

Comment: `www-data.www-data` should be : `www-data:www-data` notice `:` is it a typo mistake ?

Comment: have you cleared the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Virtual host configurations

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName your_server_name.com
    ServerAlias www.your_server_name.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
```

and you could add an record to your host file:

```
www.laravel.co.uk
```

For more information
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-err-name-not-resolved-error/

Comment: I have added the ServerName and ServerAlias and it hasn't worked. Here is my revised laravel.conf:`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.laravel.co.uk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel.co.uk/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel.co.uk>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: @RichardManson : did it work?
can you include full virtual host file ?

Comment: I'm afraid it hasn't worked yet. Upon visiting my server's ip address or www.*domain*.co.uk it still returns the error code "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Comment: have you added the dns record or is this a local project ?

Comment: I'm currently trying to upload the project onto a VPS server I have purchased. Where can I update the dns record? That might be what I need to get it going

Comment: in local have you edited host file ?  127.0.0.4      www.laravel.co.uk
I`ve edited answer too

Comment: Within my /var/local directory I don't have a hosts files on my server. Should I create one?

Comment: If it`s in server, dont`. Just point out the DNS and will get resolved after sometime (probably within few hours after pointing DNS to server )

Comment: @RichardManson a hosts file should be used on your client such that it knows which server to contact if you enter a host name into your browser

Comment: I have a support ticket open with my hosting, as I don't have an option for the DNS  Management on the cPanel, like their documentation suggests. Is there a way to manually create an A record for DNS, using FTP and SSH?

Comment: Nope, what you have to do is get your public ip of server and point that to domain record where you purchased it frim

Comment: https://www.name.com/support/articles/205188538-Pointing-your-domain-to-hosting-with-A-records

Comment: I have pointed the domain to the ip address, using the link you shared. I will close the question when I see if it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So I currently have my DNS pointed to ip address by using:                
HostName - www RecordType - A(Address) Address - **.***.***.***. I have done the same with @ and * for the HostName. Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: If you pointed DNS properly it should be working. BTW, what`s your service provider?

Comment: The service provider for my vps is a2Hosting. I'm hoping that DNS is taking its time to fix itself, otherwise I'll need to see if something other than the DNS is causing the issue. Any clues about other problems that would return the error, DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN?